# Angular Opening a Dialog when an option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my app, I have a `mat-form-field` with a `mat- option.` I want a dialog to open when I select an element from the `mat-option`. Here is my code. Right now, when I select an element, nothing happens. What should I do?

HTML:

```
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Order">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef width="10%"> Sipariş No </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
                        <span *ngIf="EditIndex != i">{{row.Order?.Subject}}</span>
                        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" *ngIf="EditIndex == i" class="w-100-p" style="min-width: 100px !important;">
                            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="row.Order" required name="Order"
                                (selectionChange)="updateProducts($event.value)" style="min-width: 100px !important;">
                                <mat-select-trigger>
                                    {{row?.Order?.Reference}}
                                </mat-select-trigger>
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let order of originalSupplierOrders" [value]="order">
                                    {{order.Reference + ' - ' + order.Subject}}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
```

TS:

```
openSelectedOrderProductList(prm) {
    const dialogRef = this._dialog.open(SelectedOrderProductListDialogComponent, {
        width: "700px",
        data: prm,
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
        //console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use `valueChanges`, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69507405/5536695, inside `subscribe` u can open your dialog

Comment: Okay but what if it doesn't have a formGroup directive? What should I use then? I edited my question.

Comment: u can use `selectionChange` event

Comment: Glad to help, u can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Reactive forms, I suggest you to use `valueChanges`, you can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69507405/5536695).

Else you can use just use `selectionChange` event of `<mat-select>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger the selectionChange in  to open the dialog. Add the "openSelectedOrderProductListfunction()" to (selectionChange).

HTML:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="Order">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef width="10%"> Sipariş No </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
      <span *ngIf="EditIndex != i">{{row.Order?.Subject}}</span>
      <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" *ngIf="EditIndex == i" class="w-100-p" style="min-width: 100px !important;">
          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="row.Order" required name="Order"
              (selectionChange)="updateProducts($event.value);openSelectedOrderProductListfunction()" style="min-width: 100px !important;">
              <mat-select-trigger>
                  {{row?.Order?.Reference}}
              </mat-select-trigger>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let order of originalSupplierOrders" [value]="order">
                  {{order.Reference + ' - ' + order.Subject}}
              </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
  </td>
```